# Sluggable Doctrine behavior for Zend Framework2

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, slug

I'm using `ZF2`, `Doctrine2` and Gedmo doctrine extensions.

My slug field code is:

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug
 * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
 */
protected $slug;
```

In my `module.config.php` i have added following:

```
`'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        'backend_entity' => array(
           'class' =>'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
           'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Backend/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
           'drivers' => array(
               'Backend\Entity' => 'backend_entity',
            )
        )
    ),
    'eventmanager' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'subscribers' => array(
                'Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener',
                'Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener',
                'Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener',
                'Gedmo\Loggable\LoggableListener',
                'Gedmo\Sortable\SortableListener'
            )
        )
    ),
    'authentication'    => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'object_manager' => 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager',
            'identity_class' => 'Backend\Entity\User',
            'identity_property' => 'email',
            'credential_property' => 'password',
            'credential_callable' => function(Backend\Entity\User $user, $passwordGiven) { 
                    if ($user->getPassword() == md5($passwordGiven."salt")){
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
            },
        ),
    ),
),`
```

When i'm creating new entity, i have got error 'slug cannot be null', thus sluggable behavior seems does not work.

Any idea why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", length=128, unique=true)
 */
protected $slug;
```